# Counting dashes in sample data

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I'm doing a task in which I am told to check for the '-'s in sample data, when a - is found in the data and there are adjacent dashes within the hashes, this only counts for 1 occurrence, e.g. in this sample data the answer would be 4.

I started by creating a 2D array to populate it then I was going to check for the dashes in the array but I am a bit puzzled as to how I would go about actually counting the occurrences, Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far;

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int a = input.nextInt(); //no. of rows
            int b = input.nextInt(); //no. of columns

            String arr[][] = new String[a][b]; //array of strings of 10 x 20
            for(int i = 0; i<a; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j<b; j++){
                    arr[i][j] = input.next();
                }
            }
            //for test purposes
            for(String[] s : arr){
                for(String e : s){
                    System.out.print(e);
                }
            }
```

Here's the sample input:

```
 10 20
    #################---
    ##-###############--
    #---################
    ##-#################
    ########---#########
    #######-----########
    ########---#########
    ##################--
    #################---
    ##################-#
```

Comment: So basically you didn't do any work and expect us to do your homework?

Comment: Sounds like. But is an interesting puzzle; that's sure.

Comment: Create an `occurences` variable and increment it by 1 each time you find a dash.

Comment: It is unclear how the count would be 4 for the data shown.

Comment: It is counting the amount of dashes in clumps, adjacent up down left right.

Comment: @FredK The reason it is 4 is because in the problem it states that the dashes are like stars, if a dash has another dash either vertically/horizontally adjacent to it and should be counted as 1 occurrence.

Comment: What would the rule be if row 6 above contained "- - # - -" instead of "- - - - -' ? That is, what if one or more groups of #-signes were completely surrounded by dashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to use regex. Consider each row as string, trim string and then allow only 20 characters in string(based on your column count).

Other approaches could be to use DSL algos.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = input.nextInt(); // no. of rows
        int b = input.nextInt(); // no. of columns
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#(--+)#");
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            String temp = input.next().trim();
            if (temp.length() > b) {
                temp.substring(0, b);
            }
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I was thinking of using RegEx as a way of checking the patterns but I wasn't sure how to implement it but you've done it in a simple and understandable way. That solved my problem, thank you.